# Shiny error oon function

Tags: r, shiny, prediction

I have been strugling for hours to find out what's worng with my shiny app. The server and ui are below, as well as the function that makes the prediction for the server.

As I write in the text box the reactiveness does work, but the same error appears. I am not an expert in Shiny. This is my second app.

When I run it I get below app (image):[image]

Please help.

Function:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(quanteda)
library(stringr)

## Read-in frequencies
df1 <- readRDS("./App/nextword/g1.rds")
df2 <- readRDS("./App/nextword/g2.rds")
df3 <- readRDS("./App/nextword/g3.rds")
df4 <- readRDS("./App/nextword/g4.rds")

texti <- "i, Don't think"
texti <- corpus(texti)
texti <- corpus(tolower(texti))
## Clean input
texti <- tokenize(texti,
               remove_numbers = TRUE,
               remove_punct = TRUE,
               remove_symbols = TRUE,
               remove_separators = TRUE,
               remove_twitter = TRUE,
               remove_hyphens = TRUE,
               remove_url = TRUE,
               concatenator = " ",
               verbose = FALSE)

texti <- dfm(texti)
texti <- data.frame(word = featnames(texti), row.names = NULL, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

p <- function(texti) {

        if(texti[1, ] == "" & texti[2, ] == "" & texti[3, ] == "") {
                prediction = df1 %>%
                        select(word, Frequency)

        }   else if(texti[1, ] %in% df4$w1 & texti[2, ] %in% df4$w2 & texti[3, ] %in% df4$w2) {
                prediction = df4 %>%
                        filter(w1 %in% texti[1, ] & w2 %in% texti[2, ] & w3 %in% texti[3, ]) %>%
                        select(w4, Frequency)     

        }   else if(texti[1, ] %in% df3$w1 & texti[2, ] %in% df3$w2) {
                prediction = df3 %>%
                        filter(w1 %in% texti[1, ] & w2 %in% texti[2, ]) %>%
                        select(w3, Frequency)

        }   else if(texti[1, ] %in% df2$w1) {
                prediction = df2 %>%
                        filter(w1 %in% texti[1, ]) %>%
                        select(w2, Frequency)

        }   else{
                prediction = df1 %>%
                        select(word, Frequency)
        }

        return(prediction)
}
```

server:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(markdown)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

        pt1 <- reactive(p(input$texti)[1])
        output$texti1 <- pt1
        observeEvent(input$b1, { 
                updateTextInput(session, "texti",
                                value = paste(input$texti, pt1()))
        })
        pt2 <- reactive(p(input$texti)[2])
        output$texti2 <- pt2
        observeEvent(input$b2, { 
                updateTextInput(session, "texti",
                                value = paste(input$texti, pt2()))
        })
        pt3 <- reactive(p(input$texti)[3])
        output$texti3 <- pt3
        observeEvent(input$b3, { 
                updateTextInput(session, "texti",
                                value = paste(input$texti, pt3()))
        })
})
```

ui:

```
library(shinythemes)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
        theme = shinytheme("darkly"),
        tags$hr(),
        titlePanel("Next Word Prediction Application"),
        tags$hr(),

        mainPanel(tabsetPanel(
                tabPanel("Prediction",
                         sidebarLayout(
                                 sidebarPanel(
                                         width = 3,
                                         tags$p(""),
                                         tags$h5("Predicted next word:"),
                                         flowLayout(
                                                 actionButton("b1", label = textOutput("texti1")),
                                                 actionButton("b2", label = textOutput("texti2")),
                                                 actionButton("b3", label = textOutput("texti3"))
                                          )
                                 ),
                                 mainPanel(
                                         tags$p(""),
                                         tags$h5("Please, enter your text:"),
                                         h4(tags$textarea(id = "texti", rows = 1, cols = 30, "")))
                         )),
                tabPanel("About", includeMarkdown("README.md"))
        ))
))
```

Comment: So, I figured my 'p' function produces the incorrect number of dimensions error (e.g. texti[1, ]). texti is a data frame [1 column, 3 rows]. Any idea on how can I overcome this issue. What I wanna code is: if each row of texti is in the df, then return the highest frequency (stupid backoff model).

Comment: Since your issue is not with `shiny` per se, I recommend rewriting the main operations of your code outside of a shiny app. Repost a minimal version of your operations and you should get more help. Without having access to all of your data `df1 <- readRDS("./App/nextword/g1.rds")`, it's difficult to help you.

Comment: @ChiPak here is the main operation (which works when i do p("i", "want", "")). The operation shows a table (1:3) of the most frequent words. I think my problem comes from how I get the input in the shiny app.

`p <- function(x, y, z) {......`

Also, the df1 is a data frame that has 2 columns: "word" and "frequency".